# How do I create a solid base for a 3D Google Maps Capture?

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

A while back a found [this](https://blog.exppad.com/article/importing-actual-3d-models-from-google-maps) blog post about loading data from google maps, and I was hooked! I followed the tutorial and I've been successful in getting the data into blender, but the resulting 3D mesh is very crude. [image: top view] It's not flat on the bottom, but hollow.
[image: bottom view]
As my end goal is to 3D print this, do any of you know how to create a solid base for this mesh? (also any advice for cleaning up the "non-manifoldness" of the map)
I've uploaded the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d1EGm9Ky3vkRQzP6BTLijz09nAst3uhx/view?usp=sharing).
All suggestions appreciated! Thanks!
(P.S. Bonus points for figuring out where it is.)

Answer (score 4):

you could try this:

go in edit mode and side view of your model:

[image]

Select a good amount of bottom vertices with box select and x-ray mode on:

[image]

now press E to extrude and Z Z (yes two times to extrude in z direction)

[image]

now add a box which is just a big as you want and it should only include the vertices you just extruded like this:

[image]

give it a boolean modifier type union and you got your base:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did try it, and it returned "modifier returned error, skipping apply"

Comment: Then please make a video what you did or a step by step explanation so that I can help you